# How to get all the values from the list in firebase database using java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all the field values in a list. I tried but I got items as null. Please help me with this. I tried to get all the values using addOnChildEventListener(), but got all the elements as null. So I have no solution that how to get all those values and add them to the appropriate lists as typed in the code.

[image]

Here is the code :

```
    private void listViewDataListener() {
    FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference(classCreatorPhoneNo + "/" + "class_list" + "/" + classUuid + "/" + "attendance" + "/" + attendanceDate + "/" + subjectUuid + "/" + lectureRank)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                    studentStatusList.add(snapshot.child("student_status_list").getValue(String.class));
                    studentUuidList.add(snapshot.child("student_uuid_list").getValue(String.class));
                    cardBackgroundColor.add(snapshot.child("background_color_list").getValue(String.class));
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in all three of your `getValue` calls, so let's look at one:

```
studentStatusList.add(snapshot.child("student_status_list").getValue(String.class));
```

If we look at the `student_status_list` in your screenshot, it is not a single `String` value, but rather a list of values. So calling `getValue(String.class)` on the `student_status_list` snapshot will return `null`, because the value of that node is not a string.

If you want to show all values under `student_status_list`, you can loop over the snapshots children to do so:

```
for (DataSnapshot statusSnapshot: snapshot.child("student_status_list").getChildren()) {
  String status = statusSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
  studentStatusList.add(status);
}
```

You'll have to do the same for the other nodes: any time you have multiple children of which you don't know the keys, you can loop over the `getChildren()` to access those child nodes.

Comment: I tried, but still, I am getting an empty list.

Log :
+911234567890/class_list/d58d65e6-759b-4b4f-945d-11ca2d1182da/attendance/13-11-2021/b518d46f-946d-4ca5-9cfc-56f2d71fa5b9/1
2021-11-21 11:46:39.229 4652-4652/com.vrs.attendy D/RetakeAttendance: studentStatusList : []

Comment: Now it is working. My fault was I was using childEventListener() instead I have to use addListenerForSingleValueEvent().